# How do I Docker COPY as non root?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While building a Docker image, how do I `COPY` a file into the image so that the resulting file is owned by a user other than root?

Answer (score 430, accepted):

**For versions v17.09.0-ce and newer**

Use the optional flag `--chown=<user>:<group>` with either the `ADD` or `COPY` commands.

For example

```
COPY --chown=<user>:<group> <hostPath> <containerPath>
```

The documentation for the --chown flag is now live on the main [Dockerfile Reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

*Issue [34263](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34263) has been merged and is available in [release v17.09.0-ce](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v17.09.0-ce).*

---

**For versions older than v17.09.0-ce**

Docker doesn't support `COPY` as a user other than root. You need to `chown` / `chmod` the file *after* the `COPY` command.

Example Dockerfile:

```
from centos:6
RUN groupadd -r myuser && adduser -r -g myuser myuser
USER myuser
#Install code, configure application, etc...
USER root
COPY run-my-app.sh /usr/local/bin/run-my-app.sh
RUN chown myuser:myuser /usr/local/bin/run-my-app.sh && \
    chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/run-my-app.sh
USER myuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/run-my-app.sh"]
```

Previous to v17.09.0-ce, the Dockerfile Reference for the `COPY` command said:

> All new files and directories are created with a UID and GID of 0.

---

**History**
This feature has been tracked through multiple GitHub issues: [6119](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6119), [9943](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/9934), [13600](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/13600), [27303](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/27303), [28499](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/28499), [Issue 30110](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30110).

[Issue 34263](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34263) is the issue that implemented the optional flag functionality and [Issue 467](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/467) updated the documentation.

Comment: This is frustating, since chown-ing a lot of files has become an incredibly slow since the overlay2 has become the default storage-driver

Comment: Yep, besides, it creates a large extra image layer for no apparent reason (in my case: >300MB for running `chown` on 40MB of files).

Comment: There is one benefit also for running chown along with COPY command which is size reduction. If we run those two command separately (COPY <host_path> <source_path>; chown other_user:other_user) then it created one extra layer which eventually doubles the image size.

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver. Thank you so much, solved a problem I'd been fighting for a few hours.

Comment: We found out the hard way that the docker server version is important.

Answer (score 0):

i did like this & is perfectly

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.17
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
RUN mkdir /app && chown app:app /app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=app:app package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=app:app . .
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ["npm","start"]
```