# Using a user other than root causes permission denied

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a `Docker` image using a user other than `root`. My `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine3.12

...

# Add user
RUN addgroup --system cetacean && \
    adduser --system mobydick --ingroup cetacean --no-create-home

USER mobydick

...

# Copy startup files
COPY --chown=mobydick:cetacean docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY --chown=mobydick:cetacean docker/docker-entrypoint.d/* /docker-entrypoint.d/
COPY --chown=mobydick:cetacean docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

But, when I try to start a container I get:

> ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec:
> "/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied": unknown

From my understanding, using `--chown=mobydick:cetacean` when copying the files should set the appropriate permissions.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the file executable?  You'd change that with `chmod` to modify the file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of docker you are using. This is working only for version v17.09.0-ce and newer as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766665/how-do-i-docker-copy-as-non-root). If your are usin an older version, you can copy then change the permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure why but after rebuilding everything seems ok. Cheers